# create summany report in jmeter from command line

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter version : 2.10. I test has couple of Http samplers. When i run the test from command line 
`jmeter.bat -n -t  "C:\Jmeter Projects\TestSuite.jmx" -l "C:\Jmeter Projects\testResult.xml"`

the result of the test creates "testResult.xml" but when i open it the data is in cvs format

```
1384844043490,1527,HTTP Request-1,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,2776,1527
1384844045046,350,HTTP Request-2,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,395,350
1384844045411,4890,HTTP Request-3,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,977530,4888
1384844050304,286,HTTP Request-5 ,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,4091,28
```

There is no header. I do not mind csv format if i can get the table header or the .jtl format.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was since JMeter 2.8 that the default JTL format is CSV as opposed to XML. I didn't try this myself, but this should work for you: 
`-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml`

Comment: in the csv format is possible to get the table header. I do not know what each row means

Answer (score 0):

Just make the changes as suggested by Alon and execute your test plan. Saving report as .jtl file.

```
jmeter.bat -n -t "C:\Jmeter Projects\TestSuite.jmx" -l "C:\Jmeter Projects\testResult.jtl"
```

Then using JMeter plugins generate the  kind of report you wish for.